# facebook doesn't read any opengraph tags from my blog pages when they are posted

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I cannot seem to get facebook to recognize the opengraph tags on the archive pages of my blog.  Every archive blog post seems to have this issue, however the homepage works fine.

Please see this post as an example:

http://www.geekmagazine.org/2013/02/09/leatherman-skeletool-giveaway/

How can I fix this?

Comment: what does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say?

Answer (score 0):

According to [FB's Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.geekinsider.com/2013/02/09/leatherman-skeletool-giveaway/) You have 2 errors.

1. **Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed:** 
   Admins And App ID Missing:  fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.
   Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
2. **og:image should be larger:**  Provided og:image is not big enough. Please use an image that's at least 200x200 px. Image 'http://www.geekinsider.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/skeletool-fanned-602x1024.jpg' will be used instead.